# How to create 'general margin' on Activity

Tags: android

On my Activity i have 8 LinearLayout.
I want to define a margin to all of them ( all of them will have the same margin value )

Is it possible to define 'global margin' and each of the 'LinearLayout' that exist on my Activity will contain the margin that i define on the 'global margin' ?

( this will save me time to define margin for each of the 'LinearLayout' )

Comment: I think you can use padding on parent layout of all those 8 linearlayout.

Answer (score 3):

Define a dimension resources `res/values`, for example:

```
<resources>    
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And then you can use in your layout xml on every `View`, for example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/appsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I suggest you to read more about [resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Comment: you just add value as const and glue them to the LinearLayout. this is not what i looking for - i need something like we have on microsoft WPF .. global attribute

Comment: In that case formulate better your question and give some more information like code example or target mockup